# *ngFor on Bootstrap "Alert self closing"

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement the following example but with ngFor:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/alert/selfclosing/stackblitz.html
That is, it would require that each time the "Change Message" button is pressed, a new instance of the message appears, being able to have several "Alerts" on the screen concurrently. The problem is that I don't know how the ngFor should be implemented since the item I should iterate over has the @ViewChildren decorator. So I was wondering if someone could guide me on how I could achieve the above behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link is broken. It just takes me to the homepage of stackblitz.

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/alert/selfclosing/stackblitz.html